# The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install Mac OS X Mountain Lion to a virtual machine (VMWare). Every time I power on the machine, it goes to the apple logo and pops up with the error: "The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.".

I've literally been searching for a solution for the past 2 hours and I'm getting nowhere.

If anyone has any idea on how to fix this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not a Mac expert, but I do know that if you're not running OSX on Apple hardware, (VM or not), you're breaking the licensing agreement.  More than likely the OS has detected that you're not following the license agreement and the OS is what's blocking you.  In order for you to continue legally you will need to purchase Apple hardware.  If you do not plan on buying Apple hardware, you're on your own.

Comment: You say you're using VMware, but what specifically?  VMware Fusion on a Mac OS X host?